# How to upgrade all modules to the required version?

Tags: magento2

I did `(setup:upgrade composer:update && composer:install setup:static-content:deploy)` but it's no helped,

**Please help me, thanks**

> Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento
>   root directory. The following modules are outdated: The following
>   modules are outdated:

```
Amazon_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.2

Amazon_Core db data version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.2

Klarna_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 4.4.4, currently installed - 4.5.2

Klarna_Core db data version: defined in codebase - 4.4.4, currently installed - 4.5.2

Amazon_Login db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.1

Amazon_Login db data version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.1

Amazon_Payment db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.1

Amazon_Payment db data version: defined in codebase - 2.1.0, currently installed - 2.1.1

Klarna_Ordermanagement db schema version: defined in codebase - 4.3.4, currently installed - 4.4.1

Klarna_Ordermanagement db data version: defined in codebase - 4.3.4, currently installed - 4.4.1

Klarna_Kp db schema version: defined in codebase - 5.4.4, currently installed - 5.5.1

Klarna_Kp db data version: defined in codebase - 5.4.4, currently installed - 5.5.1

Dotdigitalgroup_Email db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.6.0, currently installed - 2.6.1

Dotdigitalgroup_Email db data version: defined in codebase - 2.6.0, currently installed - 2.6.1

Vertex_Tax db schema version: defined in codebase - 100.2.0, currently installed - 100.2.1

Vertex_Tax db data version: defined in codebase - 100.2.0, currently installed - 100.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to Go to **Database > setup_module** tabel and `delete` all the
>   above modules entiries

Comment: and what then ? I do setup:upgrade, but  in data version column added null, and now give an error Amazon_Core data: current version - none, required version - 2.1.0

Comment: you need to do composer update. that can reenter the entries of modules.

Comment: composer update, does not create all the modules.